# Eloquent: How to return the matching rows of two datasets

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an accessor function for my `User` model which returns all the conversations of which a User is a participant.

```
    public function getConversationsAttribute()
    {
        $results = DB::select('SELECT * FROM conversation_user WHERE user_id = ?', [$this->id]);

        $conversations = array();

        foreach($results as $result){
            $conversation = Conversation::find($result->conversation_id);
            array_push($conversations, $conversation);
        }

        return $conversations;
    }
```

Now suppose I have two users `$userA` and `$userB`, how can I return the conversations of which both users are participants?

i.e., the common results between `$userA->conversations` and `$userB->conversations`

I imagine a `UNION` operator for duplicates is what is required.

What is the:

1. MySQL solution
2. Eloquent solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using intersect method of Laravel Collection, you can write

```
collect($userA->conversations)->intersect($userB->conversations);
```